# When I'm typing an Xpath or CSS selector in the console why won't matching results appear while typing? Results only appear after pressing Enter

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

So previously when I was using the Chrome Console to type Xpaths or CSS selectors, any matching results would automatically appear below and would update as I typed. However for some reason now when I'm typing the Xpath or CSS selector, no results appear while I'm typing. The results will only appear after I press the Enter key? Anyone know why this is occurring? I assume I changed some type of setting accidentally or something.

Image of results when typing vs results only after pressing Enter:
[image: Image of results when typing vs results only after pressing Enter]

I tried typing Xpaths or CSS selectors i.e $x("//button") and while typing there's no matching results that appear. Only after pressing Enter do the matching results appear

Comment: https://crbug.com/329409675. It's fixed in Chrome Canary which you can install separately.

Comment: @wOxxOm: That's worthy of being an answer.